Spring boot custom deserialization HandlerMethodArgumentResolver
I have a spring boot web app, that utilize strategy pattern, based on a specific value lets call is StrategyProp.
Meaning, many properties are defined as Interfaces with implementations depending on what strategy to use.
This is all fine, given @RequestBody RequestInterface that holds the StrategyProp, I have just created a custom deserializer, that does the job for me correctly.
But not all endpoints look this way, some endpoints take a property as a header, @RequestHeader(), or  @RequestParam().
In my mind, the solution would be for me to write a HandlerMethodArgumentResolver,
where I define how to do the request deserialization for me.
But since spring boots default AbstractNamedValueMethodArgumentResolver and for example RequestHeaderMethodArgumentResolver is needed to handle this, and I cannot find a way to extend this logic, this seems to not work as I would expect in spring boot?
I do also understand that i could just make sure that the values are just defined as Strings in the endpoint signature, and in the controller do the instantiation before passing it down into the service, but this is not desired as it would include a lot of manual work and code for each case.
So, how can i in Spring boot handle custom deserialization of properties sent as query param or headers in a uniform way.
For instance I get PropInterface as a header or query param, and StategyProp as a query param. With HandlerMethodArgumentResolver, I would easily be able to resolveArgument and instantiate the PropInterface as the correct implementation, base don the StrategyProp.
But its not supported to extend this behavior in this way?
What other options in spring boot are there?

I suggest that your controller method takes arguments:
@PostMapping("/thing")
fun postThing(
   @RequestHeader("strategy") headerStategy: String?,
   @RequestParam(name = "strategy") paramStrategy: String?,
   request: HttpServletRequest,
) 

Then you pass these to a common function to manage your deserialization.  This function, as it has access to the Headers/Params can configure the deserializer appropriately.  Then you pass to that the input stream of the Request object.
